# С чего начать? Книги, курсы, видеоуроки. C#

Tags: c#, книги

Хочу научиться кодить, желательно на C#. Проблема в том, что мои навыки ограничиваются, в лучшем случае, –массивами на паскале, и вся литература, какую не встречаю, более продвинутая, нежели хочется. Посоветуйте книжечки, пожалуйста. Видеоуроки, курсы тоже подойдут.
  Если вы считаете, что для начала лучше не Си, то какой именно язык лучше поджодит? (желательно тоже с литературой по нему).
  С чего начинали вы? P. S. мне 15 лет, учусь в 9 классе.

Comment: Вам [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105).

Comment: Начните с того, что твёрдо усвойте: языки Си и C# - абсолютно разные (а также C++). Аналогично Java и JavaScript - совершенно разные. В приличном обществе за их путаницу бьют ногами.